# Find isomorphism for an operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

[image]

I was trying to solve this problem, but am having trouble seeing why it is an isomorphism. To map from R* to G, I think that the phi function would be Phi(x)=x/2 but that doesn't work. This phi function does not preserve the operation because if we take Phi(ab)=ab/2, but Phi(a)=a/2 and Phi(b)=b/2. So the operation is not preserved.

Comment: What is $R^*$? The additive group?

Comment: no, its the multiplicative group

Comment: $f(x)=2x$ should work here. $f(x)*f(y)=(2x)*(2y)=\frac{2x2y}{2}=2xy=f(xy)$

Comment: but wouldn't f(xy)=2xy, where f(x)=2x and f(y)=2y, so f(xy) does not equal f(x)*f(y)

Comment: I just realized my mistake, you are right Leafar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=2x$ should work here. $f(x)*f(y)=(2x)*(2y)=\frac{2x2y}{2}=2xy=f(xy)$

Answer (score 1):

Try the function
$$
\phi: x \mapsto 2\,x
$$
Now, show that $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)*\phi(y)$.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking too hard. you are correct